# Интересное окно в iOS, хочу такое же

Tags: objective-c, ios7, дизайн

Увидел красивое окошко, когда лазил в iBooks, теперь хочу такое же, ниже рисунок, ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно, что бы появилось, и как в него запереть кнопки?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Окно называется `UIPopoverController`, нативный элемент для `iPad`.

[image]

[Хорошо бы почитать.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Ладно уж, копипастьте.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137851/)

Это отдельный UIView, на нее можно поместить не только кнопки, а вообще любые элементы интерфейса (которые будут смотреться на нем логично), часта практика создания внутри `Popover'а` отдельного `UINavigationController'а` для упорядочивания иерархии `view` внутри этого элемента.

Для `iPhone`а  Apple такой не предоставляет, но можете сделать сами из `UIView` или чтобы не велосипедить поищите  в сети готовые решения.

Comment: @AlexThumb, спасибо вам большое, копипастить не очень хочу, за ссылки отдельное спасибо!